# EXCEL VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run the mentioned vba code as a macro . I am trying count certain cells in a column until a particular value. and then delete the entire column range just before that particular value.
I have put this code inside a loop to apply it on all the worksheets in a workbook.

I am getting the error at Do While statement

```
Public Function StringFormat(ByVal mask As String, ParamArray tokens()) As String
 
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(tokens) To UBound(tokens)
        mask = Replace(mask, "{" & i & "}", tokens(i))
    Next
    StringFormat = mask
 
End Function
Sub delcol()

Dim ac As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim a As Long

'counting the worksheets

ac = Application.Worksheets.Count

'looping through the worksheets

For i = 1 To ac

    Worksheets(i).Activate
    
    j = 1
    a = 0

'counting the no of rows until value - "Empcode" occurs

        Do While Cells(j, 3).Value <> "Empcode"

            a = a + 1
            j = j + 1
    
        Loop

    Range(StringFormat("a1:a{0}", a)).EntireRow.Delete


Next i


End Sub
```

I am very new to learning vba hence apologies for any silly mistakes in the code.. Please help.. much needed

Comment: No need to count rows, readup on the worksheet Find or Match functions.  You can also use a 'for each' loop to enumerate the sheets in a Workbook.  If you haven't already don so, please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and review the code inspection results you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Delete Rows Above a Matched String In a Column

- The error will occur e.g. when `Empcode` is not found. Then your code will run until it fails to read the non-existing cell `C1048577`.
- Another issue is that your comparison is case-sensitive e.g. `Empcode` <> `EmpCODE`. To make the comparison case-insensitive, you could use the `StrComp` function:

  ```
  If StrComp(CStr(Cells(j, 3).Value), "Empcode", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
  ```

  Note that the comparison when using `Application.Match` is case-insensitive as illustrated in the following code.

**An Improvement**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteTopRows()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, RowIndex As Variant
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        RowIndex = Application.Match("Empcode", ws.Columns("C"), 0)
        If IsNumeric(RowIndex) Then ' found
            If RowIndex > 1 Then ' not found in the first row
                ws.Rows("1:" & RowIndex - 1).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```